# Error Library web3 and Webpack in react and angular

Tags: reactjs, webpack, web3js

I work with "react": "^17.0.2",
I tried to add the web3 library by npm i web3
But when I try to instantiate my web3 object like this
web3 = new Web3((window as any).ethereum);
Or like this
web3 = new Web3();

And I try to start my app (npm start)

I get a lot of errors

- about my webpack I have to add some fallback in my webpack.config.js

```
Compiled with problems:
```

> ERROR in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 3:16-43
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in
> 'C:...\node_modules\cipher-base'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
> - install 'stream-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:   resolve.fallback: {
>   "stream": false }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 9:193-227
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in ....
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/account.js
> 71:31-48
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in ...
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/address.js
> 14:31-48
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in ... ERROR in
> ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/object.js 46:31-48
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in ...
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/index.js 31:74-91
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in ... ERROR in
> ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js
> 7:193-227
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in ...
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 30:11-26
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in ...
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 32:12-28
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in ...
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 37:11-26
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in ...
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 39:12-28
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in ...
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 41:9-22
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in
> 'C:...\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
> - install 'os-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:   resolve.fallback: { "os":
>   false }

- a lot of errors like this : Failed to parse source map from 'C:....\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request-upload.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

> > WARNING in ./node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/coders/fixed-bytes.js Module
> > Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js): Failed to
> > parse source map from
> > 'C:...\node_modules@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\coders\fixed-bytes.ts'
> > file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> > 'C:...\node_modules@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\coders\fixed-bytes.ts'
> > @ ./node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/abi-coder.js 13:0-55
> > 76:17-32  @ ./node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/index.js 4:0-56
> > 6:0-204 6:0-204  @ ./node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js 28:21-59
> > 30:16-55  @ ./node_modules/web3-eth/lib/index.js 47:10-33  @
> > ./node_modules/web3/lib/index.js 34:10-29  @
> > ./src/components/Authenticate.tsx 7:0-24 14:19-23 14:24-42  @
> > ./src/App.tsx 5:0-53 10:35-47  @ ./src/index.tsx 7:0-24 11:33-36
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/coders/null.js
> Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> Failed to parse source map from
> 'C:...\node_modules@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\coders\null.ts'
> file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> 'C:...\node_modules@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\coders\null.ts'
> @ ./node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/abi-coder.js 14:0-42
> 50:19-28  @ ./node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/index.js 4:0-56
> 6:0-204 6:0-204  @ ./node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js 28:21-59
> 30:16-55  @ ./node_modules/web3-eth/lib/index.js 47:10-33  @
> ./node_modules/web3/lib/index.js 34:10-29  @
> ./src/components/Authenticate.tsx 7:0-24 14:19-23 14:24-42  @
> ./src/App.tsx 5:0-53 10:35-47  @ ./src/index.tsx 7:0-24 11:33-36

I used the basic template given by npx create-react-app Appname --template typescript
And then added web3 library (npm i web3)

And tried this code

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import detectEthereumProvider from '@metamask/detect-provider'
import Web3 from 'web3';

const Authenticate = () => {

```
const web3 = new Web3();

}

return (
    <div>
        TEST
    </div >
);
```

};

export default Authenticate;

Comment: Same. There's a closed git issue. https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/4090
But I haven't had success.

Comment: A possible solution, for now, is to downgrade "react-scripts": "^4.0.3". At least that worked for me.

Comment: downgrading react-scripts worked for me

Comment: Downgrading react-scripts to 4.0.3 is the temporary solution :
* modify react-scripts to "4.0.3" in package.json
* remove node_modules folder
* npm install && npm install web3
* npm start

You may encounter an error about Webpack, this could be solved by adding an .env file with `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` inside.

Answer (score 0):

Install react-scripts @4.0.3

```
npm install --save react-scripts@4.0.3
```