# How to create React App including Web3 using create-react-app? I am getting Module not found Error. BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, web3js

I am new to Web3 and I am trying to create a react app integrated with web3. Below are the steps I followed in Ubuntu.

```
    create-react-app app_name
    cd app_name
    npm i --save web3
    npm start
```

and everything worked fine, I got the react app home page.

[image: React default page]

Now, as soon as I put the following line of code in the App.js the app breaks and I get the following long error. (See below, row 5)

```
import Web3 from "web3";
```

[image: App.js file screenshot]

The error I get is as follows.

[image: React error page]

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 3:16-43

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/gkv/Stuff/Tutorial/Projects/react/lottery-react-new/node_modules/cipher-base'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 9:193-227

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/gkv/Stuff/Tutorial/Projects/react/lottery-react-new/node_modules/eth-lib/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/account.js 71:31-48

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in '/home/gkv/Stuff/Tutorial/Projects/react/lottery-react-new/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
    - install 'assert'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/address.js 14:31-48

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in '/home/gkv/Stuff/Tutorial/Projects/react/lottery-react-new/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
    - install 'assert'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/object.js 46:31-48

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in '/home/gkv/Stuff/Tutorial/Projects/react/lottery-react-new/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
    - install 'assert'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/index.js 31:74-91

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/gkv/Stuff/Tutorial/Projects/react/lottery-react-new/node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 7:193-227

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/gkv/Stuff/Tutorial/Projects/react/lottery-react-new/node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/eth-lib/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 30:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/gkv/Stuff/Tutorial/Projects/react/lottery-react-new/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 32:12-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/gkv/Stuff/Tutorial/Projects/react/lottery-react-new/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-ws/lib/helpers.js 11:12-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in '/home/gkv/Stuff/Tutorial/Projects/react/lottery-react-new/node_modules/web3-providers-ws/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "url": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 37:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/gkv/Stuff/Tutorial/Projects/react/lottery-react-new/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 39:12-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/gkv/Stuff/Tutorial/Projects/react/lottery-react-new/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 41:9-22

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/home/gkv/Stuff/Tutorial/Projects/react/lottery-react-new/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 43:10-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in '/home/gkv/Stuff/Tutorial/Projects/react/lottery-react-new/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "url": false }
```

I tried multiple stackoverflow post but none of them seems to have proper solution.

- [Error Library web3 and Webpack in react and angular [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70382479/error-library-web3-and-webpack-in-react-and-angular)
- [Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\dev\jszip-test\node_modules\jszip\lib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55601669/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-stream-in-c-dev-jszip-test-node-modul)
- [I am getting this error whilr importing Web3 from web3 in react js 17.0.1.how to fix this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70401928/i-am-getting-this-error-whilr-importing-web3-from-web3-in-react-js-17-0-1-how-to)

If someone could help that would be great. I have been struggling with this for 5 days.

Comment: Could you please show your package.json file ?

Comment: The error message is literally telling you what's wrong with it. You don't have polyfills for given packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `npm install @web3-react/core web3 @web3-react/injected-connector` after running `npm uninstall web3` and deleting `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`

You **DO NOT** need to downgrade react or install any polyfill plugins for this

Comment: not working....

Comment: Downgrade react-scripts to 4.0.3

Answer (score 2):

Web3 github page provides a solution here: https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js#web3-and-create-react-app

This solution takes advantage of react-app-rewired package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired

Polyfills can be installed via node-polyfill-webpack-plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-polyfill-webpack-plugin

The benefits of this solution:

- no need to eject and make modifications to config file --> react-scripts build will still work
- no need to downgrade react-scripts to lower versions

Answer (score 1):

That is because Webpack 5 no longer does auto-polyfilling for node core modules.

Simply in order to modify the webpack.config.js in Create React App, you have to run

npm run eject

this will create a `config` directory and inside you will have `webpack.config.js`.

```
 npm i node-polyfill-webpack-plugin
```

then inside webpack.config.js:

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin")
```

add this to `plugins` array

```
plugins: [
    new NodePolyfillPlugin()
  ],
```

I explained how to set up with create-react-app here :

[Web3 Issue : React Application not compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70472965/web3-issue-react-application-not-compiling/70512623#70512623)

I also explained to solve with webpack:

[Webpack breaking change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70559396/webpack-breaking-change)

Comment: Hi Yilmaz, thank you for the link however the only thing that worked for me was to downgrade the react version.

Comment: @GKV you mean create-react-app. downgraded CRA uses webpack4, and webpack includes the polyfolls. But when packages get bigger in size, they remove some functionalities. So webpack5 removed all the node core modules

Comment: Hi @Yilmaz, I added following in the package.json (    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3"), deleted the node_modules and installed everything again using npm i command.